# OpenCV Should I use smart pointers to prevent memory leak

Tags: c++, opencv, pointers

i have a OpenCV program for preprocessing and detecting text area for OCR.

For example in this part of program:

```
    cv::Mat image;
    cv::Mat outImage;
    cv::Mat image_blurred_5x5_kernel;

    cv::resize(image, outImage, cv::Size(), .75, .75);
    cv::GaussianBlur(image, image_blurred_3x3_kernel, cv::Size(3, 3), 0);
```

The program creates 3 images; original, resized and blurred one. I'm only going to use the last image i acquired. For example after resizing the original image and storing it in some variable, i won't be using original image anymore.

but as you see i created and used objects themselves, i am wondering is using smart pointers would result in better memory control? Or destructors are enough for this and difference between two methods is negligible? Execution time is my priority, rather than space usage.

Comment: cv::Mat itself is some kind of smart pointer. The object is only a "header" with the image meta information. The data pointer is using reference counting and will get freed after the last cv::Mat object with that data is destroyed. So typically, there is no use in using pointers or smart pointers for cv::Mat objects at all, neither from speed nor from leak perspective. `cv::Mat a = b;` will deep copy the meta information of the image (size, type, etc. just a few values) and link the data pointer of a to the same data that is used by b (no deep copying of the pixels).

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Micka i'm diving straight into it then :)

Answer (score 2):

`cv::Mat` is itself managing its resources, which will be released when the destructor is called. Since you put them on the stack, that will be handled automatically when you go out of scope.

You should use smart pointers if you were not putting the objects on the stack, i.e.

```
cv::Mat* image_ptr = new cv::Mat; // now you need to handle memory, since the allocated object will not be deleted automatically when changing scope
auto image_smart_pointer = std::make_unique<cv::Mat>(); // allocated object will be deallocated correctly when changing scope, since image_smart_pointer is destructed at change of scope.
```

Comment: Thank you Mikael, this will save me a lot of work, never been happier for an answer :)

Comment: important to mention, that cv::Mat's pixel data already is allocated on the heap, while the Mat object itself is some kind of smart-pointer. Have a look at: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html

Comment: @Micka for the question "should I manage resources when using cv::Mat?", I don't think that's necessarily important. Any container should clean up their own resources upon destruction - the user just needs to make sure this is triggered (scope change, or delete). How `cv::Mat` is handling its own resources is internal information IMO. The interested is welcome to read the docu though.

Comment: If you wrote "Good to mention", I would have agreed though :)